# Is Armor:1 from Inhuman Toughness and a Kevlar shirt cumulative?

Tags: dresden-files

I was not able to find anything on this in the rulebooks.
It seems logical, but it is a quite powerful combination.

Can I put a Kevlar shirt on a Goblin for an effective Armor:2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think not.

On a side note, on page 202, it is written:

> Do weapons rating stack? What about armor?
>
> No, they don't unless a power says otherwise. [...]

As Inhuman Toughness don't say that the rating stack, I think it doesn't.

> Hard to Hurt. You naturally have Armor:1 against all physical stress.

I think that when they say "naturally" they mean that it is the rating you have without any armour. Anyway, if it doesn't say it stacks, it doesn't stack.

Answer (score 3):

***Possibly.***

I agree with the answer from Flamma that Standard Armor bonuses do not stack. However I think I did find details that lead to a possibility that Natural Armor and extra Armor may indeed stack based on situation:

> P. 152 Your Story: Stunt: Tough Stuff, The stuff of blunt
>   trauma—fists, sticks, and stones—pose little trouble for you. Against
>   such things, ***you have a natural Armor:1 (which stacks with other forms
>   of protection)***. This does not apply to things like blades, bullets,
>   and burns, but it makes you a beast in a burly brawl.

Thus, **I think a reasonable case could be made for having Natural Armor and Fabricated Armor stack in certain situations**, or against certain types of attack. I'd suggest using the stunt above as a guideline, and add a specific short list of items or attacks the two armor types will stack against and then assume that they don't stack versus every other sort of attack. (Example: Ogre-Scion Changeling with Inhuman Toughness and Titanium Chain Mail, let the Armor Bonuses stack against fists, small weapons, and small arms fire; thereby making layers of toughness so that the creature difficult to hurt with a knife, but if the Wizard cuts loose with a blast of flame only the strongest form of armor is effective...)

***Alternately,*** I also personally like the idea of layers of protection, and there is some examples in the source material of Michael Carpenter having full plate armor with ballistic kevlar worn beneath it, with a cumulative effect of being stronger armor against swords, knivs, and bullets. —That said, I do think that having **multiple layers or types of armor may give the combatant a tool to use in a defensive maneuver**.

Example: A burly Changeling with Inhuman Toughness has Natural Armor 1, but is also employing a Wooden Shield worn on their offhand. In a battle, the Changeling performs a maneuver "Shield at the Ready" giving them a one time tag on that aspect for the next exchange granting them an additional +2 to their defense (Athletics) action. The Changeling could then either pay a fate point to continue invoking that maneuver aspect, or perform another similar maneuver in subsequent exchanges like "Keeping the Shield Held High" or something like that, which would allow another free tag as above. -Rinse and Repeat.